# Docker containers connection issue

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

I have two containers. One of them is my application and the other is ElasticSearch-5.5.3. My application needs to connect to ES container. However, I always get "Connection refused"

I run my application with static port:

```
docker run -i -p 9000:9000 .....
```

I run ES with static port:

```
docker run -i -p 9200:9200 .....
```

How can I connect them?

Comment: Why cant you use docker networking https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/

Answer (score 0):

You need to link both the containers by using `--links`

1. Start your ES container with a name `es` -

   `$ docker run --name es -d -p 9200:9200 .....`
2. Start your application container by using `--links` -

   `$ docker run --name app --links es:es -d -p 9000:9000 .....`

That's all. You should be able to access ES container with hostname `es` from application container i.e `app`.

try - `curl -I http://es:9200/` from inside the application container & you should be able to access ES service running in `es` container.

Ref - https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/#communication-across-links

Answer (score 0):

I suggest one of the following:

1) use [`docker links`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/) to link your containers together.

2) use [`docker-compose`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) to run your containers.

Solution 1 is considered deprecated, but maybe the easier to get started.

First, run your elasticsearch container giving it a name by using the `--name=<your chosen name>` flag.

Then, run your application container adding `--link <your chosen name>:<your chosen name>`.

Then, you can use `<your chosen name>` as the hostname to connect from the application to your elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a `--network` set on your containers?  If they are both on the same `--network`, they can talk to each other over that network.  So in the example below, the `myapplication` container would reference `http://elasticsearch:9200` in its connection string to post to Elasticsearch.

```
docker run --name elasticsearch -p 9200:9200 --network=my_network -d elasticsearch:5.5.3

docker run --name myapplication --network=my_network -d myapplication
```

Learn more about Docker networks here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/